# Buying specific token on Binance testnet using python

Tags: web3.py, testnets, pancakeswap, binance-smart-chain

I have written a script that works fine on bsc  main network  but when I am trying to buy the same on the testnet I get an error of transaction underpriced.

```
from web3 import Web3
snipeBNBAmount = 0.0009


web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/"))



walletAddress ="0x776DD2229088fA48212E7e1c479F591451b90fC5"
if web3.isConnected():
    print( " BSC TESTNET  Node successfully connected")
balance = web3.eth.getBalance("0x776DD2229088fA48212E7e1c479F591451b90fC5") # here balance is in wei
b =web3.fromWei(balance,"ether")

# pancakeswap factory
#pancake_factory = '0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73'  #Testnet  #0x6725F303b657a9451d8BA641348b6761A6CC7a17
pancake_factory ="0xB7926C0430Afb07AA7DEfDE6DA862aE0Bde767bc"
pancake_factory_abi =" I put abi here"
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancake_factory, abi=pancake_factory_abi)
"""Connection to Pancakeswap"""
# #pancakeswap router
pancakeSwapRouterAddress ="0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3"  #Testnet
#pancakeswap router abi
pancake_abi= "I put abi here"


contractbuy = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeSwapRouterAddress, abi=pancake_abi)

def Buy():


    tokenAddress ="0x78867BbEeF44f2326bF8DDd1941a4439382EF2A7"


  


    tokenToBuy = web3.toChecksumAddress(tokenAddress)
    spend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd")  # wbnb contract address

    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress)
    pancakeswap2_txn = contractbuy.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
        # tokenA, tokenB when buying with 2 token
        0,  # tokenB,
        [spend, tokenToBuy],
        walletAddress,
        (int(time.time()) + 10000)
    ).buildTransaction({

        'from': walletAddress,
        #'value': web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether'),
        'value': web3.toWei(snipeBNBAmount, 'ether'),
        # This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from  | Comment out for token
        'gas': 300000,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress),
    })
    # Sign transaction with priavte key here
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, config.private)
    tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    print("Snipe was succesfull, bought: " + web3.toHex(tx_token))
    exit()
```

This is the error i get
`ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'transaction underpriced'}`

Using https://amm.kiemtienonline360.com/#BSC testnet settings
and https://pancake.kiemtienonline360.com/#/swap pancake testnet

Comment: I edited the build transactions settings and it seems to work but i still wish to understand why is it failing at this gas price settings on testnet 'gas': 3000000,
                'gasPrice': web3.toWei(20, 'gwei'),

Comment: Usually underpriced occurs when you have a pending transaction and you reused its nonce.